# Ratio between node distances in a connected undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'll appreciate any help in the following question:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected undirected finite graph.
>   Let $\def\MaxD{\operatorname{MaxD}}\MaxD(v)$ ($v$ is a vertex) be the *maximal distance* of $v$ from any vertex in $G$.
>
> Prove for every two vertices $v_1$,$v_2 \in V$:
>   $\MaxD(v_1)/\MaxD(v_2) \le 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\MaxD{\operatorname{MaxD}}$Denote by $d(u,v)$ the distance of two vertices $u,v \in V$. For any $v \in V$ we have 
$$ d(v_1, v) \le d(v_1, v_2) + d(v_2, v)$$
taking maxima, we obtain
$$ \MaxD(v_1) \le d(v_1, v_2) + \MaxD(v_2)$$
Now $d(v_1, v_2) \le \MaxD(v_2)$, giving 
$$ \MaxD(v_1) \le d(v_1, v_2) + \MaxD(v_2) \le 2 \MaxD(v_2). $$

Answer (score 0):

The MaxD($v$) is called the eccentricity of the vertex. Diameter $D$ is the maximum eccentricity of any vertex in the graph and Radius $r$ is the maximum eccentricity of any vertex in the graph. Your question is equivalent to the following:

$$r \leq D \leq 2r$$

The first inequality is obvious. For the second use the triangle inequality between the two diametrical vertices (having eccentricity $D$. There are two such. why??) and the vertex with eccentricity $r$. $D\leq r+r$. Hence the result.